# Does Android Studio have an NDK memory viewer?

Tags: android, android-ndk, android-studio-3.0, lldb, memoryview

I am porting a C library code for windows into android

When I create a **dynamically allocated array** in the NDK C code, the variables viewer window only shows me the address of the first element, and the value of the first element

I would like to see **all the array's members** in the phone's memory

Is there a memory viewer or something similar for NDK in android studio?

Or as an alternative, can I do some kind of memory dump in the lldb console?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can print a ***dynamically allocated*** int array using LLDB `print` (in short `p`) command like below:(modify the **size** and **type** according to your own case)

```
(lldb) print *(int (*)[5])foo2
```

It will give output **all the elements** of the int array. See below screenshot:

[image]

For a GUI style, you can select **Variables** tab and add a new watch using similar statement as command line said above, see below screenshot:

[image]

And then:

[image]

Unfold the watched statement, you will see all the elements as below:

[image]

---

**Edit #1**

Using `parray` command is simpler:

```
(lldb) parray 5 foo2
(int *) $5 = 0x000072e200e2da70 {
  (int) [0] = 20
  (int) [1] = 8
  (int) [2] = 55
  (int) [3] = 6
  (int) [4] = 52
}
```

Comment: thank you very much. I have done something similar to this when I was using lldb in xcode (ios) and I feel things would be much more convenient with a memory viewer. Do you know if android studio even has a memory viewer? Basically I want to be able to enter a memory address and then see all the contents of memory starting from that point onward (like in visual studio)

Comment: Also, do you know if it is possible to start the python interpreter in the lldb console? I typed 'script' in the console but it didn't do anything. lldb website says this shuld start the python interpreter: https://lldb.llvm.org/python-reference.html

Comment: @user13267, see my updated answer for GUI “memory viewer “

Comment: @user13267, here https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/blob/master/lldb/examples/scripting/tree_utils.py is the python script example, but honestly, i haven't tried with it yet.

Comment: @user13267, Have I answered your question?

Comment: sort of, still not exactly what I was hoping for but very helpful non the less